# typedef type * type::* , what is it?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
  struct myType { myType * ptr; };
  typedef myType * myType ::* other_type;
```

What is the second line typedef'ining? Is that a member function that returns a myType pointer or something else?

Comment: I guess, it will be a little more readable when written like this: `typedef myType* myType::*other_type;` (without several spaces)

Comment: The equivalent C++11 syntax is slightly cleaner: `using other_type = myType* myType::*;` although the pointer to member syntax remains awkward nonetheless. Since we are in the subject, the pointer to method syntax is `using method = return_type (Object::*)(arg0_type, arg1_type, ...);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That defines `other_type` as a pointer to a member of `myType` where said member is itself a pointer to `myType`.  For example, you could use it this way:

```
other_type x = &myType::ptr;
myType mine;
mine.*x = &mine;
```

Why you would do that, I can't say.

Comment: C++ is the ultimate language for creating such code-monsters. My favourite is `const int const * MyClass::MyMethod(const int const * param) const { }`

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's a shame that this code is in the product we're developing. I would rather die than write code like this where other people need to spend time even to figure out formatting issues.

Comment: @user3498783: You're welcome.  It doesn't have to be a shame--you're developing the product, you can make it better!

Comment: @JohnZwinck I wish I were allowed to do things like that but my manager won't allow me. That really makes me cry :(

Comment: @spook half of those `const` do nothing: move them to the far side of the `*`.